# Scientific Notation as a Double java Android

Tags: java, android, string, double

If this was a string and it was parsed as a double. Would java be able to process this as the expected value or would I need to change the format of these numbers? Would I need to remove the "+" or change e to "E"?
1.3870574e+01

Comment: Why don't you just type out the code, run it, and see if it works correctly?

Comment: Well it apparently can read that file type. Done and done.

Comment: It's not a file type, it's a number representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string parsed to a double just fine on my system.

See [Double.valueOf(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)